# How to fetch json data in react?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, async-await, axios

```
useEffect(async () =>
{
    const fetchData = async () =>
    {
        const result = await axios("")
        setposts(result.data)
    }
    fetchData();
    
    
}, [])
```

Rendering :

```
posts.map(post => <li>{post.name}</li>)
```

Json File :

```
[
   {
       "id": 1,
       "vendor": "Gap",
       "name": "Men's Pullover Sweatshirt",
       "image_src": ["https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0455/2176/4502/files/Sweater_0.jpg?v=1603266982"],
       "price": "74",
       "tag": "T-shirt",
       "compare_at_price": "200",
       "options": [
           {
               "id": "1010",
               "name": "Size",
               "value": "US 8"
           }, {
               "id": "1011",
               "name": "Size",
               "value": "US 9"
           }, {
               "id": "1012",
               "name": "Size",
               "value": "US 10"
           }, {
               "id": "1013",
               "name": "Size",
               "value": "US 11"
           }, {
               "id": "1014",
               "name": "Size",
               "value": "US 13"
           }
       ]
   },
```

im facing issue to retrieve the data from json file Like i m not able render the data so please help over this

Getting error while mapping the data

im facing issue to retrieve the data from json file Like i m not able render the data so please help over this

Comment: 1. More code. 2. Post the error message.

Comment: I guess you need to get method to reach your data like await axios.get(baseURL)....

Comment: @codemonkey Error is : TypeError: posts.map is not a function

Comment: @AhmetSuhanOka I m getting data from Json i m facing issue while rendering the data

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() =>
{
    const fetchData = async () =>
    {
        const result = await axios.get("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0455/2176/4502/files/products.json")
        setposts(result.data)
    }
    fetchData();
    
    
}, [])


posts?.map(post => <li>{post.name}</li>)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with this file: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0455/2176/4502/files/products.json

It returns a an invalid JSON string. So when your axios gets its contents, it sets your `posts` variable to a simple string, which obviously cannot be mapped through. Hence the error.

The reason axios does not convert it into a JS array is because the file does not contain valid JSON to parse.

The reason the JSON in the file is invalid is because it has a trailing comma after the very last object of the array. See image:
[image]

Comment: Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working for you is, `result.data` is a string, not an array.

You'll have to convert result.data to array with `JSON.parse`

Also, the json you're using has a training comma which has to be handled for `JSON.parse` to work

following code worked for me:

```
export default function App() {
  const [posts, setposts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(async () => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get(
        "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0455/2176/4502/files/products.json"
      );
      let regex = /\,(?!\s*?[\{\[\"\'\w])/g;
      let correct = result.data.replace(regex, "");
      setposts(JSON.parse(correct));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <li>{post.name}</li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```